# How to properly load gmail api to angular 2 app

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

I am kind of new to angular 2 so ill try to explain the requirement in details.
The app I build has a login page (/login) and has the settings page (/settings).

when the user access the login page the gapi var is initialized properly then the user logs in to the app.

Once the user is in he has the settings page. the issue starts when the user refresh the page, when that happens the gapi var is no longer recognized and become undefined. My though is that the gapi library is not getting loaded and therefore it fails.

I placed the following code in the app index.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
  var CLIENT_ID = '***.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
  var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

  // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
  // included, separated by spaces.
  var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

  /**
   *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
   */
  function handleClientLoad() {
      console.log("handleClientLoad")
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }

  /**
   *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
   *  listeners.
   */
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      console.log("client init");
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen();

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      //updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());

    });
  }


</script>

<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload=this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad();
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()";>

</script>
```

To conclude how can I properly load the gapi module to handle the above refresh scenario?

I tried to work with the solution from [Best way to wait for 3rd-party JS library to finish initializing within Angular 2 service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506602/best-way-to-wait-for-3rd-party-js-library-to-finish-initializing-within-angular) however it didnt work, gapi is still undefined.

Comment: Facing the same problem in Angular 5.xx.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is create a custom `GoogleService` that is responsible for initializing the GAPI client in Angular apps. Instead of interacting with the GAPI client directly, my app interacts with the `GoogleService`.

For example (using Angular 9.x)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GoogleService {
  private gapiAuth?: Promise<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth>;

  constructor() {
    // Chrome lets us load the SDK on demand, but firefox will block the popup
    // when loaded on demand. If we preload in the constructor,
    // then firefox won't block the popup.
    this.googleSDK();
  }

  async signinGoogle() {
    const authClient = (await this.googleSDK()) as gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth;
    const googleUser = await authClient.signIn();
    const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    return {
      type: 'GOOGLE',
      token: googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token as string,
      uid: profile.getId() as string,
      firstName: profile.getGivenName() as string,
      lastName: profile.getFamilyName() as string,
      photoUrl: profile.getImageUrl() as string,
      emailAddress: profile.getEmail() as string,
    };
  }

  async grantOfflineAccess() {
    const authClient: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth = (await this.googleSDK()) as any;

    try {
      const { code } = await authClient.grantOfflineAccess();

      return code;
    } catch (e) {
      // access was denied
      return null;
    }
  }

  // annoyingly there is some sort of bug with typescript or the `gapi.auth2`
  // typings that seems to prohibit awaiting a promise of type `Promise<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth>`
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299128/type-is-referenced-directly-or-indirectly-in-the-fulfillment-callback-of-its-own
  private googleSDK(): Promise<unknown> {
    if (this.gapiAuth) return this.gapiAuth;

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=gapiClientLoaded';

    this.gapiAuth = new Promise<void>((res, rej) => {
      (window as any)['gapiClientLoaded'] = res;
      script.onerror = rej;
    })
      .then(() => new Promise(res => gapi.load('client:auth2', res)))
      .then(() =>
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: environment.google.apiKey,
          clientId: environment.google.clientId,
          discoveryDocs: environment.google.discoveryDocs,
          scope: environment.google.scopes.join(' '),
        }),
      )
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('there was an error initializing the client', err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      })
      .then(() => gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return this.gapiAuth;
  }
}
```