# Type is referenced directly or indirectly in the fulfillment callback of its own 'then' method

Tags: typescript

An errors blows up when using the typings for the the Google Auth2 API - `@types/gapi.auth2`. The compiler throws an error `1062` if I create a promise that resolves with the `gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth` type.

`Type is referenced directly or indirectly in the fulfillment callback of its own 'then' method.`

The typings have this little quirk:

```
class GoogleAuth {
    ...
    /**
     * Calls the onInit function when the GoogleAuth object is fully initialized, or calls the onFailure function if
     * initialization fails.
     */
    then(onInit: (googleAuth: GoogleAuth) => any, onFailure?: (reason: {error: string, details: string}) => any): any;
    ...
}
```

The code in use is something like this:

```
async function getGapi() {
    return new Promise<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth>(resolve => {
        ...
    });
}
```

It doesn't matter whatever is inside the promise scope, as soon as it has that `GoogleAuth` type - it's upset.

The problem is definitely related to the typings and it's probably easy to create a wrapper or ignore the error entirely. The GoogleAuth object is 'thennable' but why should that cause any problem? Is there a circular reference or something?

What's more troubling is there is very little on the 1062 error. I haven't yet resorted to reading the compiler code, but so far I can't figure out what it's trying to tell me.

Comment: I found similar issue reported for `ember-data` typings in [ember-typings repo](https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-typings/issues/74). They've chosen to modify their typings.

Comment: So does that suggest a problem in Typescript itself or a problem in the auth2 typings? It works perfectly fine as plain-old Javascript code so I would suggest it's a Typescript problem.

Comment: Interesting. When you say that it works in javascript, does that mean that `onInit` callback receives `googleAuth` object that actually has `then()` method when `GoogleAuth.then()` resolves? That would be weird because promise is guaranteed to resolve to something which is not a promise.

Comment: No you're right, I've assumed something there.
This suggests that we simply cannot use the GoogleAuth object in a promise - even in javascript.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauththenoninit-onerror

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edit: Answering my own question.*

Google's documentation explicity says this:

> Warning: do not call `Promise.resolve()` and similar with the result of
>   `gapi.auth2.init()`. As the GoogleAuth object returned implements the `then()`
>   method that resolves with itself, it will create an infinite recursion.

This means there will be trouble whether we're using Typescript or even plain Javascript.

So here Typescript is protecting the user from an infinite recursion. Whether or not that is it's intention, I don't know. The wording seems to suggest it's issue is entirely a typing problem or limitation of the compiler. But it's actually doing an important job.

TL;DR: The promise result is another promise which returns itself. The compiler error is guarding against infinite recursions.

Comment: Note: that warning in the documentation must be outdated. I just tested it, and the then() method resolves with a different object that does not contain its own then() method. So there's no infinite recursion. The issue now is just that the typescript types are incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to omit `then` from the type.

```
async function getGapi() {
  return new Promise<Omit<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth, "then">>(resolve => {

  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, although that's a neat workaround and makes the compiler happy, I think Typescript is doing the right thing here. See my accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, but my answer is more in response to the title of your question. I came up with that solution while working on the definitions for the gsap library. The `then` method gets nulled out on fulfillment, and that was the only way I could make it work. https://github.com/greensock/GSAP/blob/d05746483fd6c7fef1e15d56ef980f17f03d6be8/types/animation.d.ts#L45

Comment: That's quite interesting. Who applies the null on fulfilment? Is it a JS native thing or a cheeky fix from a library author? If it's the latter it means that your answer is not the full solution and that there must also be guarantees that the `then` method is removed.

Comment: It's a fix by the library author, but the fix guarantees that the `then` property will be nulled when used with `Promise.resolve()` and similar. So yes, my solution might not be correct for the Google Auth 2 API library, but it is correct for the gsap library.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I found to circumvent this error

```
private async loadGapiAuth() {
  await new Promise((resolve) => gapi.load('client:auth2', resolve));
  await new Promise((resolve) => gapi.auth2.init(GAPI_CONFIG).then(resolve));
}
```

then I can do this:

```
await this.loadGapiAuth();
const auth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous to use Promise with any objects with it's own `then()` method. See [@gwilz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59655446/4661625) answer. You will be trapped in an infinite loop!

One way to workaround is to actually remove `then()` method:

```
async function getGapi() {
  return new Promise<Omit<gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth, "then">>(resolve => {
    ...get auth object...
    delete auth.then;
    resolve(auth);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan. 2022, the types have been fixed. The error no longer occurs. See the [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/57981) for details.